# Django MultiValueDictKeyError Passing input type file

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am getting this error when I am trying to pass the value of the folder to another html.
[image]

I have stored the form in a database in DB Browser Sqlite. I am trying to pass the input type = file to another HTML. So that when I view the existing type = file, the file will automatically be shown.

**Below is an attachment from submitclaim.html**

```
 <form action="/newclaim/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="receipt">Receipt:  </label> <br>
    <input id="receipt" type="file" name="receipt_field">
</form>
```

**This is my verfiyexistingclaims.html**

```
 <form method="POST" action="/verifyexistingclaims/{{claims.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="receipt">Receipt: </label>
    <input id="receipt" type="file" name="receipt" value={{claims.receipt}}>
</form>
```

**This is my views.py**

```
def financeverifyclaims(request, id):
    context = initialize_context(request)
    user = context["user"]

    # get original object
    claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":

        # update original object

        claims.receipt = request.FILES["receipt"]

        # save it with original `ID`
        claims.save()

    return render(
        request, "Login/verifyexistingclaims.html", {"claims": claims, "user": user}
    )
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

# Create your models here.
class SaveClaimForm(models.Model):
   
    receipt = models.FileField(upload_to='receipts/%Y/%m/%D', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg','png'])])
```

Comment: use `request.FILES.get('receipt')` to check if **receipt** is present or not.

Comment: Not working out for me @Vishal

Comment: Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what do you want to do when the **receipt** is not present?

Comment: I want to make the uploading of receipt compulsory

Comment: are you using `ModelForm`? can you post the code of your `Model` and `ModelForm`.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I have updated

Comment: read about `ModelForm` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: I have no isssues with model forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a default value in case it does not exist, i.e.:

`claims.receipt = request.FILES.get('receipt', False)`

Comment: After i submit the pics, can it still show?